# access two gsm interfaces in Android

Tags: android, api, embedded, driver, gsm

Does Android 2.3.4 (or 4.0) support dual gsm interfaces in a phone? What will be required to implement something like this? Software-wise? Can you point me to some documentation? We want to be able to select the GSM interface to make a particular call. Moreover, display the status of the signal strength for each interface in the notification area.

Thnx. Any and all help will be appreciated.

CC

Answer (score 0):

All you need is in this research paper:
part 6.1 RIL Proxy
http://www.sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/13-andrus-online.pdf

If you want to add gsm interface to any phone, you will need to implement your RIL library. It has standardized interface.